# unable to delete google play services data

Tags: google-play-services

This question  is maybe similar to [Cannot delete Google play services data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459980/cannot-delete-google-play-services-data). I'm not sure, so I'm posting it here.

In the settings of the google play services application, I cannot display the data used by this application. It always displays "computing..." even after several minutes of waiting. When I try to delete all data (by pressing the button at the bottom), the settings closes with no result.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG5X0.png)

Could someone help me please?

I've tried to update the application using google play store but there is no option "update" nor "install" in google play store. I've tried also to use adb command to whipe data at /sdcard/data/ but it didn't work because my phone was not rooted. I'm not ready to root my phone. It's risky.

I'm sorry for any spelling or other mistakes. I am not anglophone.